# Bad alignment of \begin{array}...\end{array} with LaTeX2HTML

Tags: align, arrays, latex2html

I recently used `latex2html` (released January 1, 2021) to convert a mathematical LaTeX paper with 100 plus equations of varying complexity with very good results, except for one flaw. Which I have traced down to the `\begin{array}...\end{array}` environment. The MWE given below shows how the alignment changes with a) the amount of white space, and also how it b) differs from the alignment of the number 0:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
%
\noindent{}%
Alignment of {\tt \textbackslash begin\{array\} 0 \textbackslash  end\{array\}}:
%
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{c}
 0
\end{array}
& =
\begin{array}{c}
 0
\end{array}
\\
& =
\begin{array}{c}
 0
\end{array}
\end{align}
%
Alignment of {\tt \textbackslash begin\{array\}0\textbackslash end\{array\}} (without embedded spaces):
%
\begin{align}\begin{array}{c}0\end{array}&=\begin{array}{c}0\end{array}\\&=\begin{array}{c}0\end{array}\end{align}
%
Alignment of number {\tt 0}:
%
\begin{align}
 0
& =
 0
\\
& =
 0
\end{align}
%
\end{document}
```

The output generated by `latex2html` looks like this:

[image]

Because the alignment depends on the amount of white space in the formula I suspect there could be a parser error here, but since I am new to `latex2html` I am asking for help. Remark: I can of course can avoid the problem by reformulating the math expression but I thought that `\begin{array}...\end{array}` is something that ought to work with `latex2html`.

Update:
I have quickly tested `tex4ht`. The command:

`htlatex mwe.tex "xhtml,html5,mathml,charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"`

produced the output:

[image]

which actually looks promising, but by switching to the more up-to-date command:

`make4ht mwe.tex "mathjax"`

the output was changed to:

[image]

which shows that there is still a parser problem. Also, the full non-MWE paper revealed several new errors (which, however, are not relevant to the question at hand.)

Comment: `latex2html` mainly programmed by using `Perl` script, better consider to switch over to `TeX4ht`, which fully works purely based on `LaTeX` codes and tags

Comment: do you have up-to date distribution? your example works correctly for me with `make4ht mwe "mathjax"`.

Comment: Apparently not, `make4ht --v` says v0.3k while the latest version on CTAN appears to be v0.3l. However, it is the latest available in MacPorts.